# How to represent a lagged Fibonacci generator using list abstract data types?

Tags: random, numbers, generator, abstract-data-type

A *pseudo-random number generator* is a function of no arguments that returns, when called
repeatedly, a sequence of values that appears to be random and uniformly distributed over a range {0,...,N - 1}, where N is typically 2^k and k is the number of bits in a computer word (e.g., 2^32 or 2^64 for many computers).  A *lagged Fibonacci generator* for the range {0,...,N - 1} returns the values xn = (xn-r +xn-s) mod N, where r and s are integer constants of the algorithm (0 < r < s) and the initial "seed" values x0, x1,...,xs-1 are determined in some other way.  The values r = 5 and s = 17 are recommended because they result in a sequence that does not repeat value for a very long time.  Explain how to represent a lagged Fibonacci generator using list abstract data types. What representation would be most appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

pseudo random number generators have *state*, which in case of your example is a list of 17 integers.

You can implement this using a simple `array` and an `insert` method. Every time you call `insert`, `i`th element is copied to next position. Discard the first element & insert the current random number.